# SWIFT: Why isn't my URL to maps app working correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url, annotations

I have code where a user taps an annotation, then clicks a button which gives them directions that the city of said annotation is located in, by sending them to the Maps app. Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func routingButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let annotationAsCLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: coordinatesInTransition.latitude, longitude: coordinatesInTransition.longitude)
    
     geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(annotationAsCLLocation) { (clPlacemark, error) in
         //print("Reverse geocoding resulted in an error: \(error ?? "" as! Error)")
        
        // I found the URL strings documentation for opening the route in the Maps app here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html
        if let url = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=\(clPlacemark?[0].locality)&dirflg=d&t=m") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
     }
}
// Create function that uses the distanceTo and determines which aspect of the placemark is the closest to the annotation and uses that for the URL
}
```

Anyway, when I type in the locality of the CLPlacemark that is created (clPLacemark?[0].locality), the URL doesn't send me to the maps app, but when I type in the same locality raw, such as URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=Hague&dirflg=d&t=m") as opposed to the normal way, URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=(clPlacemark?[0].locality)&dirflg=d&t=m"), it works.

In essence, replacing the coded locality accessed through the placemark with the actual name is working, but the coded way isn't.  Any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle optionals.

Replace:

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=\(clPlacemark?[0].locality)&dirflg=d&t=m") {
```

With:

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=\(clPlacemark?[0].locality ?? "")&dirflg=d&t=m") {
```